# WP API 2 Category in Categories (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

I'm still learning angularjs so all this is new to me.  I have JSON data fetching from a controller and displaying the information in a html page (posts).  I pulled up the category json URL, plugged it in where I get the posts from to see if I can get the list of categories (and changed the post.name and all), but it failed to get the list.

I assume the controller needs to be completely reworked for it to work with categories?

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('myapp') 

.controller('WPCatCtrl', function( $scope, $http, DataLoader, $timeout, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $rootScope ) {

  $rootScope.url = 'http://genesis2media.com/mobile/wp-json/wp/v2/terms/category';

console.log('WPCatCtrl');

$scope.loadPosts = function() {

  DataLoader.get( $rootScope.url + 'cat' ).then(function(response) {
    $scope.categories = response.data;
    console.log( response.data );
  }, function(response) {
    console.log('error', response);
  });

}

// Load posts on page load
$scope.loadPosts();

paged = 2;
$scope.moreItems = true;

// Load more (infinite scroll)
$scope.loadMore = function() {

  if( !$scope.moreItems ) {
    return;
  }

  var pg = paged++;

  $timeout(function() {

    DataLoader.get( $rootScope.url + 'cat' + '?page=' + pg ).then(function(response) {

      angular.forEach( response.data, function( value, key ) {
        $scope.posts.push(value);
      });

      if( response.data.length <= 0 ) {
        $scope.moreItems = false;
      }
    }, function(response) {
      $scope.moreItems = false;
      console.log('error');
    });

    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.resize');

  }, 1000);

}

$scope.moreDataExists = function() {
  return $scope.moreItems;
}

// Pull to refresh
$scope.doRefresh = function() {

  console.log('Refreshing!');
  $timeout( function() {

    $scope.loadPosts();

    //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

  }, 1000);

};

   })

.controller('CatListCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, DataLoader, $ionicLoading, $rootScope, $sce ) {

 $ionicLoading.show({
  noBackdrop: true
});

 var singlePostApi = $rootScope.url + 'cat/' + $stateParams.postId;

 DataLoader.get( singlePostApi ).then(function(response) {
  $scope.post = response.data;
  // Don't strip post html
  $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.content.rendered);
  $ionicLoading.hide();
}, function(response) {
  console.log('error', response);
});

});
```

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: Failed to load resource:  the server responded with a status 404

Comment: It's giving me the links:
http://genesis2media.com/mobile/wp-json/wp/v2/terms/categorycat
http://genesis2media.com/mobile/wp-json/wp/v2/terms/categorycat?page=2

Comment: This is clearly a problem with http://genesis2media.com/ endpoint. Are you sure you have proper URLs?